# Does Kaminari load all records when call page method later?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

In my `User` model

```
def activities
    Activity.where actor_type: self.class.name
end
```

When I call `current_user.activities.page(params[:page])` in controller , I want to know it will load all activity records or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord is lazy-loading - it will only call the SQL query when you actually access the data in the result set.

It won't load Activity data until you do something like `.all` or `.each` or something else that actually requires access to the data.

Answer (score 1):

No, kaminari will not load all records at once. You can test it in the rails console:

```
current_user.activities.page(params[:page]).to_sql # => "SELECT  \"activities\".* FROM \"activities\"  WHERE \"activities\".\"user_id\" = 1 LIMIT 25 OFFSET 25"
```

As you can see, LIMIT and OFFSET are both involved into the SQL query. And of course, it's eager loading.